# Basic HTTP Authentication: User or Application?

Tags: html, security, http, rest, restful-authentication

Should be a simple answer to my question, but on the web I seem to get conflicting information.

Lets assume I have a simple API using Basic HTTP Authentication. A Mobile App uses my API on SSL to signup new users (POST) and (GET) **ANY** user information/profiles.

**Question:** Am I validating the **User** or the **Application** with HTTP Authentication?

As an example...

Lets say

api.somedomain.com/user/create

api.somedomain.com/user/{userID}

Scenario 1: the API uses Basic Authentication in the header and the application sends a  developer  usersname and password (not the user who is logged into thier app). Users can be created by the application and user accounts can be view by the app.

Cons: if someone finds out the user name and password the application is using they can create users and view an account.

Scenario 2: I validate the user over Basic Authentication not the application. this way the user can view their information when logged into the app.

Cons: the app cannot create a new user as they need to Authentication as a user first.

Now I know the first answer will be "use OAuth" but I would like an answer for basic Authentication in this case please.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have already listed the advantages and disadvantages. Now, what are your requirements?

Comment: The Mobile Application needs to allow users to signup via the APi and view other users profiles from the API. However I ONLY want the application to use the API (maybe later a few more apps will need access). My issue is that in Scenario 1 anyone with the application key could create an account. Not good! I know it will be hard to find the key put still possible given I don't have control over the mobile app.

Comment: Should I be validating the User or the Application with HTTP Authentication, or maybe both? The app is for users to create a account if they don't have one, or to view their account details or view other accounts (read only).

Comment: You don't need to require the same auth across the whole API.  If you're intent on using basic auth, you can require it for just certain resources (at least in PHP and CGI; other environments may leave auth entirely up to the web server).  Meaning you can have a sign-up API that doesn't require authentication, while everything else does.

Comment: I have found something that I think may answer My question: Quote: The first important thing is that a system making a REST query is NOT an interactive user. You should therefore NEVER require or allow the user of interactive user credentials for REST authentication. The only exception is a client/server application in which the client represents an interactive user and the protocol between client and server is a RESTful API. " http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html

Comment: What I dont get: You say "he app is for users to create a account if they don't have one", but "My issue is that in Scenario 1 anyone with the application key could create an account. Not good!" Now is it a requirement or not good that anonymous users can create an account?

Comment: @ Moritz. I only want the mobile application to allow a user via the API to create an account. Outside his application I don't want the user to be able to create an account via the API. i.e. only anonymous users via the mobile application can create an account, outside of this an anonymous user would be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in any case you have two users *(two kinds of users)*. One kind is a living humanoid, the other kind is an application.

The "application-type user" is allowed to create accounts, and the "humanoid" is allowed to view/edit his profile.

For your server the problem should be simple:

- First, **see who is authenticated**. Match the username and password and find the *client*.
- If the *client* tries to create an account, or see a profile, check whether **he is permitted to do it**.

Treat the *mobile application* just in the same way as a living human, and make them differ only in their permissions. Your *mobile application* may send you its own credentials when it tries to create an account, but as soon as some human provides his own login and password, let your *mobile application* use the ones provided by human.

Comment: Kinda makes sense I found a quote: Your REST client is not an interactive user. Customers can fudge this by creating a dedicated account expressly for the purpose of REST authentication. Unfortunately, this enables attackers to go after the interactive account as an attack vector for compromising the overall system. Furthermore, because REST is authenticating a program and not person, it allows for stronger authentication than human user ID/password schemes allow.   ----  So make by created a new table for API users is the way to go.

Comment: If you enforce the permissions properly, customers will not be able to compromise the system. From the security's point of view **there should be no difference between accessing the server from browser or from your mobile application**. You also should not trust too much your application. Allow it to execute only the actions it needs to, and nothing more. This is a wide topic, and we may soon run out of space in comments ;-)

Comment: Yes it's a big topic which is why I just wanted to look at "user" or not a "user". I think from this I have a better understanding and hopefully so will others.